# Comparing a date with Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I am using Laravel Scout to search a model, and then I'm using a filter to get past events and upcoming events.

Here is my method:

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $search = $request->get('q');

    // Laravel Scout search() method
    $users = User::search($search)->get();
    $articles = Article::search($search)->get();
    $events = Event::search($search)->get();

    $today = Carbon::now();

    $upcomingEvents = $events->filter(function ($events) use ($today) {
        return Carbon::parse($events->startDate)->gt($today);
    });

    $pastEvents = $events->filter(function ($events) use ($today) {
        return Carbon::parse($events->startDate)->lt($today);
    });

    $userCount = count($users);
    $articleCount = count($articles);
    $eventCount = count($events);
    $upcomingEventCount = count($upcomingEvents);
    $pastEventCount = count($pastEvents);
    $templateCount = 0;

    return view('pages.search.index', compact('search', 'users', 'articles', 'upcomingEvents', 'pastEvents', 'userCount', 'articleCount', 'upcomingEventCount', 'pastEventCount', 'templateCount'));
}
```

I had read a tutorial here: https://scotch.io/tutorials/easier-datetime-in-laravel-and-php-with-carbon

Reading this I saw you can get today, right now, with `Carbon::now()`.

There's also `lt()` for less than and `gt()` for greater than.

In my filter I've grabbed the start date and compared it to `Carbon::now()` but for some reason, it does not return what i expect.

In my database `startDate` is a `VARCHAR` but in my Event model I have specified the following:

```
protected $dates = [
    'startDate', 'finishDate'
];
```

This is my database table:

[image]

But in my view I get this:

[image]

Am I using `Carbon` wrongly?

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100% sure if it is necessary to have the type in DB set to `DATE` instead of `VARCHAR`.

I will just assume that it works with `VARCHAR`, too. That would mean that by setting the `$dates` array in the model, your collection will automatically create a Carbon instance of the value already.

With:

```
return Carbon::parse($events->startDate)->gt($today);
```

You are parsing an already existing Carbon instance.

Try instead:

```
return $events->startDate->gt($today);
```

Comment: I agree. Double-parsing the date is causing errors.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem happens with the `startDate` for being `VARCHAR`. You may convert it to a real date with a simple method below:

```
private function convertDateString($date)
{
    if (is_string($date)) {
        $date = Carbon::parse($date,new DateTimeZone('YOUR_DATE_TIME_ZONE'));
    }

    return $date;
}
```

You can pass your `startDate` value to in and get a real date to compare with `Carbon::now()`. Hope this helps you.